# RegExp For Uk telephone number with +44(0)

Tags: regex

Im trying to validate a Uk telephone number,

Im using this regexp:

```
   ^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$
```

This match well with almost number possibilities but these does not match:

+44 (0)7518 123 456 or +44(0)7518123456

Any one know how to amend it to achieve it?

Regards!

Comment: You should show us what other numbers you need to match

Comment: +447222555555 | +44 7222 555 555 | (0722) 5555555 #2222 and
01222 555 555 | (010) 55555555 #2222 | 0122 555 5555#222

But this already matches

Comment: It seems overly complex, for instance it uses `\+44` three times, in comparision to [this example](http://www.regxlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1421)

Comment: This is more or less working but left behind this:
(010) 55555555 and (0722) 5555555

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this quite a lot. Check out this regex101 to see if it matches your needs:
http://regex101.com/r/xP6lE7/1

```
^(\+?44)?(\(\d+\))?[\d ]+(#\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

This matches all your edge cases:

```
^(\+?44)?(?=(.*?\d){10,})( ?\(\d+\))?[ \d]+(#\d+)?$
```

The look ahead asserts there are at least 10 digits not including the country prefix.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/mQi8XM0gU3) with all edge cases you have mentioned.